# How to plot a set-valued mapping graph

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, graphs-and-networks, legending

I know that if $T$ is a single-valued mapping for example $T(x)=x^{2}$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ then its graph can be plot using

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Is there any way to plot a set-valued mapping like  $Tx=[0,x]$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.? In (2D or in 3D)?

Answer (score 2):

For example,the set-valued mapping $T x=[x^2,x^3]$,we can use `ParametricPlot`(or sometimes `ParametricRegion`)

```
ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, x^2, x^3}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, Mesh -> {{.6}}, MeshStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Or

```
Plot[{x^2, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Thanks dear @cvgmt for your kind answar. I have a question can we plot its 3D graph in the case of my example $T=[0,x]$?

Comment: @Junaid $x$ is two dimension?

Comment: Dear @cvgmt, no $x$ is a real number in the closed interval $[0,1]$. The is function maps $0$ 0n $\{0\}$, .....$0.5$ 0n  $ [0,0.5]$ ,....., $1$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Junaid We need not use 3D. Just use 2D. `ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, x}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &},  Mesh -> {{.6}}, MeshStyle -> Red]`